# Android app is saying Google Play services out of date

Tags: java, android, google-maps, mobile

I am trying to create a basic Google Maps in my Android (Java) project, but every time I try to run it, I go to the log statements and it says

```
"Google Play services out of date for com.example.findaseat.  Requires 13400000 but found 11743470"
```

Just some information about what is running:

1. Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1
   Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973, built on August 16, 2023
2. Pixel 2 Nougat API Level: 24 ABI: x86 Target: Android 7.0 (Google Play Services)

[This is what shows on my emulator when I try to run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZrx7.png)

3. These are my SDK Tools

[SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXacj.png)

4. Google Map related code:

```
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.2.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0")

}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FindASeat"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/my_map_api_key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I followed all the steps in this video for the rest of my code: [Google Maps Setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOKPQ8rYe6g)

I have tried to click on the update button on the emulator, and it asks me to sign into my google account, which I do, but everytime it gives me a server error.

[Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkO36.png)

I try to go to my emulator settings, but I get a loading screen on the play services update.

[Emulator Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSFL2.png)

I have also tried using other Emulators (Nexus, etc.) but I keep getting the same issue. I am also not sure what version to demote my google maps API version to in my build file, I have tried a bunch of numbers, and if I go too low sometimes I get errors in my MainActivity.java

Comment: "Google Play services" are an system app on the phone you have to update. Usually this happens automatically via Play Store but you can also manually update it. https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9037938?hl=en

Comment: I am creating a program on Android Studio, so it's not on my phone, but I have tried to update it manually from the emulator and it's not working

Comment: Android Studio does not execute Andrid apps. For running an app you need a phone - it can be a physical phone or an virtual phone (emulator) but you need a phone.

Comment: Sure, I have tried to manually update it using the link but that still did not fix my issue.

Comment: It could be that the device you used is still on Nougat. Or because the emulator you ran did not have a Google Play Service. Please make sure that you run an emulator with one.

Comment: Do you have any reason why you need the lowest version of Android or Android 7 on your emulator??